# gRPC API only work in localhost, not work when i publish it in somewhere

Tags: node.js, azure, grpc

I'm trying to make a Benchmark by rest vs gRPC.

I coded my rest api that receives many json objects and counts it. So i published it as a `web app on linux` with azure container ( [I published it using this way, but my image is public](http://passionatecoder.ca/Article/Deploy-Docker-Containers-to-Azure-Web-Apps-on-Linux-from-Azure-Container-Registry) ) and all **works fine**. ([docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/italojs/test-rest/))

I coded a gRPC API ( [code here](https://github.com/italojs/grpc) ), on this project, i have a `server.js` and a `client.js` at `/bin` folder, and a `.proto` file at `/protos`

this gRPC API do the same thing that REST api does, it receives many json objects and counts it.

When I run the gRPC API on `localhost` on port 80,8080,3000,3010... **it works fine**, i run my client that sends the json objects to gRPC method and it returns the line's number.

When I make a dockerfile ([docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/italojs/test-grpc/)), build it, run the grpc-image on port X and run the container in my **local machine**, **it WORKS fine too**.

When I tried to publish this container at `Web app on linux` (the same way to [publish a rest api](http://passionatecoder.ca/Article/Deploy-Docker-Containers-to-Azure-Web-Apps-on-Linux-from-Azure-Container-Registry) ) my client returns nothing. it doesn't enter into my request method, i tried to log with console.log("test") regardless of whether the request works or not.

```
client.testMethod({ lines: JSON.parse(data) }, function(err, response) {
            if(err){
                console.log('ERRO: ', err);
            }else{
                console.log('Greeting:', response); 
            }
            console.log('response: ', response); //log regardless of whether the request works or not.
        });
    console.log("finish.");
```

my client just returns "finish" because it already executed the gRPC request.

I thought it's something like the port or something this, so I created a **Virtual Machine** on Azure and I opened the 80 to http requests and the 8080 to anything that wanna enter into my VM. Inthis VM i installed nodejs and my gRPC project and run it without docker on port 80, so i tried to execute my gRPC client on my VM ip:port and **it doesn't work too**, so i published my **rest api** in this VM and **it worked**.

So i tried to publish it into my local network without docker, i run my gRPC API on a machine(that works with localhost:port) and tried to run my client on other machine(i am sure the port that i used was open), and the same thing happened, it doesn't enter into my request method, but when i do it with resp api it works.

I tried to use the [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) too, but the same thing happened.

I dont know what's happening with this gRPC server, why it isn't working when i try to access it through network?

Comment: Have you tried adding `npm rebuild` to your Dockerfile? I'm pretty sure you are copying the node_modules up since I don't see a `.dockerignore`. With them in place `npm install` probably isn't doing anything and I think gRPC relies on pre-compiled binaries. Outside of that, do you have any server logs or errors?

Comment: i published the gRPC on a VM and it work's when i access localhost (into VM) but when i acces from onother machine(in the same network or not) it doeasnt work. Every time someone access my gRPC Server i log it, and it only is logged when i run tyhe server and the client in localhost

Comment: When you say that you "opened the 80 to http requests", do you mean that you explicitly specified to Azure that it should accept HTTP traffic? Because gRPC does not use HTTP, it uses HTTP2, which is a different protocol.